# Possible Missing Word in Cover Letter

Tags: cover-letter

So I applied to two different positions at the same library. I tend to put the name and address of wherever I'm applying to on the cover letter. The first cover letter said [City] Library, and the second said [City] Public Library. I'm concerned that the first cover letter could be considered to be inaccurate. Does it make any difference?

Comment: It's probably on the same level of inaccuracy as referring to Dell Technologies as just "Dell" or referring to Apple, Inc. as simply "Apple". If the context is clear, then it's probably not an issue.

Comment: Are you worried the library you sent them to won't know it's for them?

Answer (score 10):

No.  It won't make any difference.